# Why does my code update values to null, instead of key value pair values assigned

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, postman

Why do I get null everytime I try to update my DB with mongoose through the postman PUT request where I fill in key value pair values. My code is below:

```
.put(function(req,res){

   Article.updateOne(
      { title: req.params.articleTitle },
      {
         title: req.body.title, 
         content: req.body.content
      },      
      function(err) {
         console.log(req.body.title);
         console.log(req.body.content);
         if (!err) { 
            res.send("Successfully updated article")
            console.log("update success")
         }
      })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an [update operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/) to the update document; [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set) would be appropriate.

The new update document would then look like this:

```
{
   $set: {
      title: req.body.title, 
      content: req.body.content
   }
}
```

Comment: I was using the Postman app. I realized I just needed to go to the body section and check on x www url enocded! Everything is now working as it should.